# make flash movie float to the right and have an html side menu on the left

Tags: html, flash, web, css-float, movie

I have a website built mostly in flash. The flash movie is on an html page. I want the flash movie to be in the same line with a side menu (list of links to other pages on my site).

This is my website: http://www.arielajewellery.com/gallery.html

I tried this html code:

```
<style>
.center{float: center;}
.left{float: left;}
.clear{clear: both;}
</style>
<div class="left">
<font color="white">
<h1><u>MENU:</h1></u>
 ...
</div>
<div class="center">
```

Then the whole flash movie code(which flash does automatically)

and it works perfect on my pc but on other computers you see the html list on top of the flash movie (so you actually need to scroll all the way down to practically see my site!)
can somebody please tell me what i'm doing wrong? and if possible to enter my website link and see the whole html code cuz it doesn't show here the whole thing..

Thanks a lot!

Gili

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the size of the screen. If the size of the screen is not wide enough to fit everything on it, it will break it down to the next line. Your flash movie is 900px alone and your side menu is probably another ~150px, which totals to about 1050px. Most screens are only a 1024px resolution, 16px of which are taken up my the scrollbar plus any borders the browser might have on it.

Comment: ohh! ok i changed the size of the movie and it worked thanks a lot!